# How can I fix font size between OSX and Windows?

Tags: html, css, windows, macos, fonts

So I've been putting together a website and when I tested it on a Mac I noticed the size of a few elements were off.  After some searching on the internet I found out that Windows and OSX fonts display differently to the point the size will be off (reference: http://www.rfwilmut.clara.net/about/fonts.html)

I've found all kinds of articles that discuss the issue but none where they talk about who I can fix it.  I have it set so that various elements align perfectly but different font sizes obviously mess that up.  I could go back and manually specify the size of each element but it seems like a whole lot of extra effort to get by one silly font display issue.

HTML:

```
    <article class="small_article">
    <h1>Sigma Phi Epsilon</h1>
    <p>Sigma Phi Epsilon was founded in 1901 on the campus of Richmond College (now called
 the University of Richmond) in Richmond, Virginia. The story of its founding by 12 
determined men set the stage for the growth and success of one of the country’s premier 
fraternal organizations. The history of the Fraternity reflects the times, through great 
wars and profound cultural shifts. Throughout the decades, the men of Sigma Phi Epsilon 
have practiced their values and embraced the stated desire of the Founders, “This 
Fraternity will be different.”</p>

  <li>Over the past two decades, SigEp has recruited more men than any other collegiate fraternity.</li>
  <li>Currently, over 15,000 undergraduates are SigEps, more than any other national fraternity.</li>
  <li>Nearly 300,000 lifetime members ranks SigEp among the largest national fraternities.</li>
  <li>SigEp maintains a full-time professional staff of over 35 people.</li>
  <li>The SigEp Journal has been published continuously since 1904, and is distributed to all members for life.</li>
  <li>SigEp hosts the largest biennial convention in the fraternity world: the Grand Chapter Conclave.</li>
  <li>SigEp was the first national fraternity to establish a housing trust for all chapters and create a National Housing Corporation.</li>
  <li>Sigma Phi Epsilon has the greatest number of fraternity houses, with over 200 chapter homes.  Of those, over 115 are owned by local SigEp Alumni and Volunteer Corporations.</li>
  <li>The Sigma Phi Epsilon Educational Foundation was the first fraternity foundation to build an endowment greater than $11 million.</li>
  <li>The Sigma Phi Epsilon Educational Foundation is a 501(c)(3) charitable foundation. Its program funding is planned to develop the scholarship, leadership, citizenship, and personal potential of college undergraduates.</li>
</article>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color:#D8D8D8;
    margin:0;
    font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:13px;
    padding-top: 60px;
}
.small_article{
    width:660px;
    display:block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Comment: The article that you linked is insanely old - it mentions IE4, which came out in 1997. Can you post some of your CSS for the elements where the font size differs? I have never run into this problem.

Comment: Fonts will never be *exactly* the same cross browsers / os, but that shouldn't be a real problem. Can you show us an example of where it causes issues for you?

Comment: Yeah, the article is pretty old although it seems to still relate to my issue.  The code in question really isn't anything special.  I have an <article> _without_ a set height with 3-4 <p> in it.  The <article> displays in Chrome and Safari on Win8 with a height of 429px.  However, in both Chrome and Safari on OSX it displays at 409px.  (added code in original question)